# How to fetch memory in realtime after CreateProcess?

Tags: c++, c, delphi, assembly

I have executed a process using CreateProcess, but I want to fetch or dump the memory area allocated to the process, preferably in real time. Unfortunately I do not know how to recieve the pointer to the memory are after creating the process. I've been searching around, but I have not found any useful answers so far.

If anyone could help me out, I'd be very grateful. Language does not really matter, anything will do. (However, preferably C/C++/Delphi etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `VirtualQueryEx()` to see what memory pages are used, and `ReadProcessMemory()` to read them.